# return value inside html tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the data from some social networks and put in the mongodb.

This is the information inside the html tag

```
<span class="ProfileNav-value" data-count="347235" data-is-compact="true">347K</span>
```

I was able to recover the 347K as follows

```
page = requests.get("https://twitter.com/cancaonova")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
followers = soup.find_all(class_="ProfileNav-value")
seguidores = followers[2]
print seguidores.get_text()
```

However I wanted to get the data inside the **data-cont** tag I'm trying that way, but the result was: *none*

```
page = requests.get("https://twitter.com/cancaonova")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
followers = soup.find('data-count')
print(followers)
```

Tks for you

Comment: use - soup.span['data-count']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'element.attrs' to read attribute:

```
seguidores = followers[2]
datacount = seguidores.attrs['data-count']
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
rel_soup = BeautifulSoup('<span class="ProfileNav-value" data-count="347235" data-is-compact="true">347K</span>','html.parser')
rel_soup.span['data-count']
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your code. For example, you can quote and link to the relevant documentation for beautifulsoup.